# Using Azure API Services to connect to Filemaker via ODBC

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, odbc, filemaker

I have a need to get data from a Filemaker database.

I got it working on my local computer using the Filemaker ODBC driver and `OdbcConnection`.

I need to know if there is any way to configure Filemaker ODBC driver in Azure API Services.

thank you.

Comment: Hi Dan, did you manage to find a solution to this?  I'm hoping to do something similar in my next project and checking if its feasible.